# Highcharts change line style after intersect

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a line chart made with Highcharts.

I want to change the style of the line to dotted when the lines intersect, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JpRX.png

Does somebody know if this is possible in highcharts?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions-line--dashStyle

Comment: I want to make this just when they interstect, straight line and the from the intersection to the end dotted

Comment: Make them separate series. You cannot do this with a single series. One series with solid dash style and one with dashes, as linked by MelanciaUK.

Answer (score 0):

There can be zones set for series that will enable change in color, fillColor and dashStyle.

API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones.dashStyle

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-dashstyle-dot/

```
series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            zoneAxis: 'x',
            zones: [{
                value: 8
            }, {
                dashStyle: 'dot'
            }]
        }]
```